# How to implement pub/sub socket.io client in python?

Tags: python, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I've been trying to implement the python equivalent of the code below but cannot seem to get it working.

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io('http://devel.hz.udoidio.info:5000')

socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.emit('subscribe', 'new-tx')
})

socket.on('new-tx', function (txid) {
  console.log('New tx: ' + txid)
})
```

I tried this approach but it does not seem to yield anything.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

def on_response(*args):
    print 'on_response', args

baseurl = "http://v1.livenet.bitcoin.chromanode.net"
socketIO = SocketIO(baseurl, 80, LoggingNamespace)
socketIO.on('subscribe', on_response)
socketIO.emit('subscribe', 'new-block')
socketIO.wait()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resloved the problem, below is the correct solution.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

def on_response(*args):
    print 'on_response', args

baseurl = "http://devel.hz.udoidio.info"
with SocketIO(baseurl, 5000) as socketIO:
    socketIO.on('new-tx', on_response)
    socketIO.emit('subscribe', 'new-tx')
    socketIO.wait()
```